# Load Firebase date into UITableView by observeSingleEventOfType and attach ChildAdded Observer

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, firebase

I am trying to load data, from Firebase, in a UITableView. The structure I'm loading is:

```
user: {
    "simplelogin:12": 1,
    "simplelogin:13": 1,
    "simplelogin:15": 1,
    "simplelogin:17": 1
}
```

I want to load this data a first time, when the view is loaded (or when it appeared if I am requested to do it as is), and I want to "listen" and add only all new child data to the UITableView.
However, my data are loaded twice. How can I do that?

Currently, the main parts of my ViewController are:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self

        // Load user
        loadFirebaseUser()
    }

 func loadFavoriteUser() {
        let firebaseRef = Firebase("http://...")

        // Add Observer on Child Added
        firebaseRef.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { userSnapshot in
              println("added \(userSnapshot.key)")
        })

        // Initialization
        firebaseRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { userSnapshot in
            println("value \(userSnapshot.value)")

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }
```

The output is

```
added simplelogin:12
added simplelogin:13
added simplelogin:15
added simplelogin:17
value {
    "simplelogin:12" = 1;
    "simplelogin:13" = 1;
    "simplelogin:15" = 1;
    "simplelogin:17" = 1;
}
```

Many thanks for your help

Comment: I don't understand your question, but can confirm that the output you show is expected. Firebase first fires a ChildAdded event for each child and then a Value event for all children combined. But why are you registering handlers for both events? Just ChildAdded **or** Value should be enough for most use-cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
func loadFavoriteUser() {
    let firebaseRef = Firebase("http://...")

    // Add Observer on Child Added
    firebaseRef.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { userSnapshot in
          println("added \(userSnapshot.key)")
          self.tableView.reloadData()
    })

}
```

Comment: I've found that this method is not good if you have tons of initial data. You'll want to fetch all data first, add that do your internal data, then do a reload of a tableview, and then listen to further data. For some reason though in my attempts, I get duplicate data because `.childAdded` incorrectly fetches the data that it already got from observeSingleEvent/.value again.